# Sufficient conditions for Loewner ordering of two matrices?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Le $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ two psd matrices of size $n$. Additionally we assume that the entries are *real* and *non-negative*. Does the following hold:
$$\forall (i,j) \in [n], \mathbf{A}_{ij} \leq \mathbf{B}_{ij} \implies \mathbf{A}^2 \preccurlyeq \mathbf{B}^2$$
where $\preccurlyeq$ is the Loewner partial order on the cone of psd matrices.

Comment: Say $A$ and $B$ are two psd matrices, if we know $A \preceq (1+\epsilon) B$, under what kind of extra condition, we can have $A^2 \preceq (1+O(\epsilon)) B^2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. E.g. $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}\le \pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}=B$ entrywise, but $B^2-A^2=\pmatrix{1&2\\ 2&2}$ is indefinite.